# Bluetooth Low Energy Client scan range

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon

I understand that Bluetooth Low energy(BLE) client scan for BLE peripherals. I want to know, how far,in meters, a BLE client can scan/discover a BLE peripheral.

Comment: It depends one the device you use (it's antenna), if there are perturbation (wall, etc.).

Comment: What about iPhone 5 and above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An iPhone 5 will detect a [RadBeacon USB](http://www.radiusnetworks.com/ibeacon/radbeacon/) (BLE Beacon) set at maximum transmit power about 40 meters away.  At greater distances of up to 50 meters, it might be intermittently detected, but detections are not reliable.  Outdoors with clear line of sight, it can sometimes be detected at even greater distances of up to 100 meters, but again this is not reliable.

This is typical, but just an example.  The specifics depend on the transmitting device, the receiving device, any physical obstructions, and how much radio noise is in the area.